# Partitioned Index vs Index on each partition

Tags: postgresql

In postgres 14 and above, what are the benefits of

1. Having a partitioned index on a partitioned table versus
2. Having the same index on each partition of a partitioned table, but no 'partitioned index' on the partitioned table

Benefits I can think of:

- When adding new partitions, the index is automatically created on the new partitons
- When dropping the 'partitioned index' on the root table, the indexes on the partitions are removed

**Are there more benefits of having that 'partitioned index' on the root table that 'glues together' all those indexes in the partitions? Especially when it comes to query planning and performance? Or is this 'partitioned index' on the root table merely a DBA quality of life feature?**

Comment: Per-partition/granular index is optional and can be different from other partitions, which might be useful if your partitions face different types of traffic. You can't enforce uniqueness/exclusion between partitions with per-partition indexes since other tables would be outside of their scope. Exclusion constraints aren't supported at all at partitioned table level, while unique constraints have to include the partitioning columns.

Comment: @Zegarek thank you for the valuable input of many good points that I have missed. Also, it seems that you also see no performance-reason to have an index via the partitioned table than on a per-partition basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index on a partitioned table is mostly only an insurance that the index exists on every partition. The additional difference is that a constraint on a partitioned table can only be implemented with an index on the partitioned table.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that an `insert ... on conflict` clause fails when there is no unique index on the partitioned table, even though the unique index does exist on each partition of the partitioned table.